# HTMLHelper.Beginform query

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I'm learning about HTMLHelpers in ASP.NET MVC.

To render the form HTML tag you would write something like

```
<% using(Html.BeginForm("HandleForm", "Home")) {%>
    <!--Form content goes here-->
<% } %>
```

> or
>
> ```
> <% Html.BeginForm(); %>
> … Form Contents …
> <% Html.EndForm(); %>
> ```

To render the a checkbox you would use

```
<%= Html.CheckBox("bookType") %>
```

What I would like to know is is why we need to use <% when we use BeginForm whereas we need to use <%= when we use other HTMLHelper methods

Cheers,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Html.CheckBox` returns a string of HTML containing an `<input>` tag.
You need to print this string to the page by writing `<%= ... %>`.

`Html.BeginForm` prints the HTML inside the method (by calling `Response.Write`), and doesn't return HTML.  (instead, it returns an `IDisposable`, so that you can use it in a `using` block)
Since you aren't printing its return value, you put it in a `<% ... %>` block, which executes code without printing its results.

Answer (score 1):

`<% %>` wraps a code block

`<%="string" %>` is equivalent to `<% Response.Write("string") %>`

and in ASP.NET MVC 3 you can automatically HtmlEncode with `<%: "<htmlTag>" %>`

You can definitely write `<%=Html.BeginForm() %>` but you will also need to write `<%=Html.EndForm() %>`. Wrapping `Html.BeginForm()` within a `using` block will just render the closing `</form>` tag for you.

Answer (score 0):

Because `<%=` means "Print this for me", pretty much the same as doing:

`<% Response.Write("content"); %>`

When `<%` means that you have a code-block that might do more than just print the value you have nested in it.